# Launching MacVim gives E254 cannot allocate color

Tags: vim, osx-elcapitan, macvim

When I launch `vim` I do not have issues, but when I launch `MacVim` using `mvim` from the command line I get the following error:

```
$ mvim .vimrc 
$ Error detected while processing /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-102/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/colors/macvim.vim:
line   54:
E254: Cannot allocate color MacSelectedTextBackgroundColor
line  109:
E254: Cannot allocate color MacTextColor
E254: Cannot allocate color MacTextBackgroundColor
```

I installed MacVim using `homebrew`. Homebrew 0.9.9

My OS is El Capitan 10.11.4

I am setting up my new laptop so all I have installed so far: `xcode`, `command line tools`, and `macvim`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602079/macvim-color-issues-when-launching-from-command-line) is similar, but none of the answers work for me. I tried `iTerm2`. I originally did not have a `.vimrc` and launching it from the dock rather than the command line still throws the error.

Comment: Use the MacVim's issue tracker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug that it has been already fixed. So, you have to wait for the next release.

You can see the [issue](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/issues/275) and the [pull request](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/pull/276) on GitHub.

Comment: Until then, `mvim filename.txt 2>/dev/null` will have to do.